# Removing Exchange 2016 after migration to Office 365 - will AD Exchange schema be preserved?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, microsoft-office-365

Small company has migrated to Office 365. AD Connect is running but there are no longer any on-premise mailboxes. Microsoft recommends leaving the last Exchange (there was only ever one) in place but for various reasons we would like to remove it.

**My question:** if you uninstall Exchange does it leave the Exchange AD schema in place, as this is required for AD Connect to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оnce the extended Active Directory scheme will never can not be removed. (Variants with disabling attributes, but in general, the scheme will not be deleted.)

Therefore schema extensions will remain when Exchange server is uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

As Slipeer mentioned the schema stays extended. The are a number of administrative tasks that are useful to keep an on premise server. Without it any objects created in 365 need to have remote objects mirrored in AD. Removal of objects can also be a problem (they can get out of sync).

MS has a license for Exchange that doesn't include mailbox storage specifically to help in this scenario. It is free and takes care of the above issues.

Comment: hi Tim, thanks for the comment. Can you expand on this:

"Without it any objects created in 365 need to have remote objects mirrored in AD"

as I'm not sure what you mean :-)